# Create junction table where one referenced table has a composite key as PK

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a category table which currently has only a title field (PK)

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `title` varchar(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (`title`)
);
```

and a product table with a composite key as a primary key

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `title` varchar(50),
  `vendor_name` varchar(50),
  `price` decimal(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`title`, `vendor_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_vendor_name` FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_name`) REFERENCES `vendor` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

A product can have many categories so I created a junction table. I'm struggling with the composite key from the product table. In the junction table I need to reference the combination of the product title and the vendor name foreign key. I started with this

```
CREATE TABLE `category_product` (
  ``/* product composite PK */
  `category_title` varchar(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (``/* product composite PK */,`category_title`),
  KEY `fk_category_product_category_title` (`category_title`),
  KEY ``/* product composite PK */
  CONSTRAINT `fk_category_product_category_title` FOREIGN KEY (`category_title`) REFERENCES `category` (`title`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT ``/* product composite PK */ ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

How do I handle the composite key from the product table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have also to define two columns for a double Primary KEY

```
CREATE TABLE `category_product` (
  `category_title` varchar(20),
    `product_title` varchar(50),
  `product_vendor_name` varchar(50),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_category_product_category_title` FOREIGN KEY (`category_title`) REFERENCES `category` (`title`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_category_product_product_title_vendor_name` FOREIGN KEY (`product_title`,`product_vendor_name`) REFERENCES `product` (`title`,`vendor_name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: may I ask you if you forgot the `KEY` field or if this is not needed?

Comment: you don't need a key for this relationship table, but if you like you can add one auto_incrementg or the combined between all three columns.